# Purpose of PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationToken in Spring Security?

Tags: java, spring-security, spring-boot, jwt

I am authenticating a User using [UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.2.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/authentication/UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken.html) in SpringBoot.

I am generating a token using [JJWT](https://github.com/jwtk/jjwt) for that User and returning it back.

Now the User uses that token to send any further requests to me. After decrypting the token should I be using [PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationToken](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.2.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/authentication/preauth/PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationToken.html) and set it to `SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication()`?

What is the purpose of `PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationToken`?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The Purpose of the `PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationToken` is to integrate Third Party Identity Management Systems into your Spring Application with Spring Security.

A `PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationToken` can come in the form of a HTTP Header, HTTP Parameter etc. In this case there need not be an Entire User Registration in your Application. Just storing this token and relevant data would be suffice.

You can read more on this from [Spring Security Documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/preauth.html)

For JWT Case though after decryption you can even use `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken` as decryption process will reveal the Username, Password, Authorities.

Comment: Thanks! My token does not contain the user password. Only the Username and Authorities. As successful decryption itself would guarantee that the User was authenticated earlier and token was generated by the server. Sounds right?

Comment: @amitection Your reasoning is correct. There is no need to access the database since the token holds the truth. Since it has been cryptographically signed an application can trust it without checking with the persistent storage. This is (by the way) one of the advantages of using JWT.